# Sql Server 2008 - Dropping a synonym

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a utility database (customers) on my db server where I store all of the routines used to modify data on the other databases. We recently found out that using synonyms will greatly benefit us.

```
use Customers   
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM employees.sys.synonyms WHERE name = 'tblPerson2') begin
drop synonym [dbo].tblPerson2
end
```

This doesn't work because I am using the Customers database but need to drop the synonym from my employees database.

SQL Server 2008 doesn't support this syntax -

```
drop synonym [employees].[dbo].tblPerson2
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to modify synonyms accross databases. My solution involves having to add an identical stored procedure to every database, which seems prone to error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
EXEC('USE employees;
DROP SYNONYM [dbo].tblPerson2;')
```